# Wireless USB Adapter not working on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, wireless-adapter

I am trying to install a Wireless USB Adapter but Raspbian can't detect it.

tp-link TL-WN725N | Raspbian 10.1 | Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

I think the drivers were installed correctly, but I just plugged it in - nothing on the manual - i hope its plug and play

```
root@dekopi01:/home/pi# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                  110592  5
8021q                  32768  0
garp                   16384  1 8021q
stp                    16384  1 garp
llc                    16384  2 garp,stp
r8188eu               438272  0          <---- This is the chip set name
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
sha256_generic         20480  0
cfg80211              614400  1 r8188eu
evdev                  24576  10
[...]


root@dekopi01:/home/pi# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

I havent changed anything on **/etc/network/interfaces**

The end of my **/etc/dhcpcd.conf** looks like this

> interface wlxd037453131f4
>   inform 192.168.211.201/24
>   static routers=192.168.211.254
>   static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.6

and **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** like this

> ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
>   update_config=1
>   country=DE
>   
>   network={
>           ssid="*****"
>           psk=********************************
>   }

I also tried `root@dekopi01:/home/pi# raspi-config` -> `Network Options` -> `N2 Wi-fi` but there is just an error telling me

> Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant
>   There was an error running option N2 Wi-fi

If I disconnect my LAN cable (which works fine btw) the GUI just tells me "No wireless interface found". Do I miss something? Really hope you guys have a clue for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first time I plugged in mine, it didnt recognize it either, and I had to manually set my ssid and wifi passcode from the preferences, or the console, after rebooting, the wifi list showed all nearby networks, and connected to mine perfectly, and the light on the usb started ticking afterwards

Comment: See this page, its what got my network up and running: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: Edit, I see you already sortof did that, perhaps your SSID is incorrect, Make sure theres no typos, include spaces too.

Comment: Do you find a device (mostly named phy0) with `iw list`?

Answer (score 1):

I somehow fixed the problem, but it's far from ideal. I just installed wicd (Wireless Interface Connection Daemon) and it detected the usb adapter by itself, configured my network and now it's up an running but I still dont have any idea why the dongle wasn't detected by wpa_supplicant or how to configure it for wlan on CLI.

Since you can configure your network over systemd, wpa_supplicant or oldschool with /etc/network/interfaces I have no clue what the best practise looks like.

edit to attach: since I plugged in the dongle all interfaces were renamed and `/var/run/wpa_supplicant` still got a symlink to wlan0 the other 2 interfaces are not linked ... is there a way to do this manually?

Comment: Interfaces, in particular the USB/wifi dongle, isn't detected by wpa_supplicant but by the kernel, either with compiled in drivers or with loadable modules. You may have a look at the repository with `apt list *firmware*` if you can find a loadable driver.

Comment: It might have something to do with the strange settings you put in dhcpcd.conf

Comment: Ingo, I already `apt-get install  firmware-realtek`. As you can see in lsmod and lsusb the wlan adapter is detected and since wicd could establish a connection it just seems a problem with my understanding of configuring wpa_supplicant.